# How to Update an xml file without loading the entire file in memory

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can we update an xml file without loading it entirely into memory. In the following code I want to navigate through each parent node note and update the value of the to node. How can we achieve this using C#. I have to update the to field based on some other calculation that I have in code.

```
<note>
<from>Jani</from>
<to>Tove</to>
</note>
<note>
<from>John</from>
<to>Doe</to>
</note>
```

Comment: How big is the file you want to update? Is memory really a serious concern?

Comment: yes. The file might contain more than 7 million records. So memory is a constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a streaming approach with `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`, where you simply write out everything from the reader apart from the portions you need to change.

Scott Hanselman has a [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StrippingOutEmptyXmlElementsInAPerformantWayAndTheBusFactor.aspx) post using this technique.

Comment: Note that this post is from 2005. Don't do what the blog post does: don't use `XmlTextWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use XmlReader and XmlWriter. 
here are some examples.

http://dotnetperls.com/xmlreader, http://dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter