# Update large xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm writing a tool to inject some xml nodes to existing xml file in my machine.
However, since the file is about 30MB, XDocument.Load(path) is taking forever.

for example,

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>123</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

is a part of the large xml file.

I would like to append a xml node under tag "b" like

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>123</c>
    <d>456</d>
  </b>
</a>
```

The file is located in a local folder and I want to update the existing file.

What would be the best way to update the large xml file without loading completely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't readily edit xml in place; well, you *can*, but doing so would involve computing the encoded byte size, extending the file, and copying all the data after the insertion point by n bytes (being careful not to overwrite the data you haven't read yet), and overwriting the data at the insertion point.

More typically, you might use an `XmlReader` / `XmlWriter` pair, reading and writing element-by-element, except for at the insertion point, where you write the extra element.

Neither option is trivial.

You could *try* using `XmlSerializer` instead of `XDocument` - a simpler object model (i.e. a POCO model) might be easier and more efficient to load; however, put simply: xml isn't a good format if you want to make frequent changes.

One other option you might consider: XSLT (or possibly SAX); then sweeping the model becomes the API's job, and you just need to worry about adding a template for your changes. XSLT isn't a tool everyone knows, but it will be a *lot* easier to try than `XmlReader` (a basic transform can be put together from samples in a few minutes).

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use streaming.

look at this link: http://[stackoverflow.com/questions/4255668/how-to-update-an-xml-file-without-loading-the-entire-file-in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255668/how-to-update-an-xml-file-without-loading-the-entire-file-in-memory)

hope it helped.